# Sum Formula - extend version is matching the comprised one?

Tags: calculus, summation

Could you please let me know if the formula presented below is matching the extended version?

In case it isn't, please help with the correct formula.

Please click on "Computation" in order to see the formulas.

[Computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5rrB.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it is correct, and as you notice you can further reduce it to :

$\dfrac{r}{12}\cdot\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n P_iC_i}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} P_i}$